# $3\times 3$ matrix with no real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, examples-counterexamples

I was asked this question on my hw along with any $2\times2$ matrix with no real eigenvalue and any $4\times4$ matrix with no real eigenvalue. I got the $2\times2$ which is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
-1 & -1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
can someone help me on the $3 \times 3$ and $4\times 4$, it seems really simple but I'm kind of stuck, thanks!

Comment: Any 3x3 matrix has got at least 1 real eigenvalue. Could you say why ?

Comment: For the $4\times 4$ case think about a suitable diagonal block matrix. **Hint:** use the one you got for the $2\times 2$ case.

Comment: @Thomas: any *real* $\;n\times n\;,\;\;n$ odd,  matrix has at least one real eigenvalue...

Comment: So basically a 3x3 and a 4x4 has at least one real root according to the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: What Robert Israel and DonAntonio said is correct for matrices with real entries.  But for complex entries you could also just write $\begin{bmatrix} i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3i \end{bmatrix}$.  Don't assume that the entries of matrices are necessarily real numbers.  A matrix can be defined over any field.

Comment: Yes the homework question asks if a matrix has real numbers then what 3x3 and 4x4 matrix is there that has no real eigenvalues, but you guys answered it because a 3x3 and 4x4 with real entries must have one real eigenvalue, thank you!

Comment: @Jessica, a $4$ x $4$ matrix need not have any real eigenvalues. See my example below.

Comment: I see yours has eigenvalues of i and -i. Do 3x3 matrices follow the same pattern?

Comment: @DonAntonio thanks, that was a hint for Alexis

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're talking about matrices with real entries: any nonconstant cubic polynomial with real coefficients has a real root, by the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is to use the Frobenius [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Given some equation:
$$P(\lambda) = \lambda^4 + c_3\lambda^3 + c_2\lambda^2 + c_1\lambda + c_0$$

You can construct a matrix that has that characteristic polynomial:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & -c_0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & -c_1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -c_2 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & -c_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So just choose roots that are imaginary but have pair with a complex conjugate so you get a real polynomial:

$$P(\lambda) = (\lambda - a + bi)(\lambda - a - bi)(\lambda - c + di)(\lambda - c + di)$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & -(b^2 + a^2)(d^2 + c^2) \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 2(ac^2 + ad^2 +  a^2c + b^2c) \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -4ac - a^2 - b^2 - c^2 - d^2 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 2(a + c) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

As long as $b \ne 0$ and $d \ne 0$ you'll have a whole lot of matrices without real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

For a $4$ x $4$ matrix, why not let $$J = \begin{pmatrix}
0&-1&0&0 \\ 
1&0&0&0 \\ 
0&0&0&-1 \\ 
0&0&1&0 
\end{pmatrix}?$$

Then, what are the eigenvalues? What are the dimensions of the eigenspaces? How does the characteristic polynomial show up in the diagonal blocks?

In fact for any $n$ x $n$ matrix, where n is even, we can simply repeat these blocks along the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the eigenvalues are roots to the characteristic polynomial.